# My cakePHP console doesn't work.

Tags: cakephp

I looked to so many tutorials and I added the path C:\wamp\www\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console on Environment Variables, but still I can't open it from comand promt with the word cake. 
Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: You should NOT have to add any cake path, see [here why](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/03/console-for-cakephp/#important). Instead just make sure the PHP one is in the paths and you are good to go if done properly (as per docs).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a project from scratch with the console on windows, the right command is `cake bake` .

However, I do highly recommend you download the project skeleton from github. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp, then you can run `cake bake` from inside `C:\wamp\www\projectname\app>`, and you'll be able to manage your web site's mvc

good luck